# Error: IPC channel is already disconnected

Tags: node.js

Where/when should I catch this error?

```
Error: IPC channel is already disconnected
```

This is called from `child_process` (using `cluster`) module when I call `.disconect()` multiple times. I know that I shouldn't call this twice (or more), but sometimes I don't have control over this. Eventually how to prevent calling this multiple times? This code doesn't works:

```
try {
  if (worker.state !== "disconnected" && worker.state !== "dead") {
    worker.disconnect();
  }
} catch (error) {}
```

**EDIT:**

This is stack trace of this error:

```
events.js:71
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
Error: IPC channel is already disconnected
    at process.target.disconnect (child_process.js:392:26)
    at ProgressTracker.callback (cluster.js:437:20)
    at ProgressTracker.check (cluster.js:94:32)
    at Object.Worker.disconnect [as 44:2] (cluster.js:445:16)
    at handleResponse (cluster.js:149:41)
    at respond (cluster.js:170:5)
    at handleMessage (cluster.js:180:5)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at handleMessage (child_process.js:269:12)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:293:9)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of an old post, but I ran into this issue in my project.

I found the the `worker.suicide` api is now deprecated (see: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_suicide).

It is now suggested to use `worker.exitedAfterDisconnect` (see: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_exitedafterdisconnect).

So, to use Kirill Zhirnov's example:

```
if (!cluster.worker.suicide) {
    cluster.worker.disconnect();
}
```

would become:

```
if (!cluster.worker.exitedAfterDisconnect) {
    cluster.worker.disconnect();
}
```

`exitedAfterDisconnect` will be undefined until either `.kill()` or `.disconnect()` is called on a worker, then it will be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use worker.suicide to prevent calling .disconnect() multiple times:

```
if (!cluster.worker.suicide) {
    cluster.worker.disconnect();
}
```

http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_suicide

> Set by calling .kill() or .disconnect(), until then it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in NodeJS 7.10 and NodeJS 8.0

How to check:

```js
if (child.connected) {
    child.disconnect();
}
```

ChildProcess which hasn't disconnected:

```js
ChildProcess {
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: { internalMessage: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _closesNeeded: 2,
  _closesGot: 0,
  connected: true,
  signalCode: null,
  exitCode: null,
  killed: false,
  spawnfile: '/usr/bin/nodejs',
  _handle: Process { owner: [Circular], onexit: [Function], pid: 25424 },
  spawnargs: [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', './dist/child.js' ],
  pid: 25424,
  stdin: null,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null,
  stdio: [ null, null, null, null ],
  channel:
   Pipe {
     bytesRead: 0,
     _externalStream: {},
     fd: 14,
     writeQueueSize: 0,
     buffering: false,
     onread: [Function],
     sockets: { got: {}, send: {} } },
  _channel: [Getter/Setter],
  _handleQueue: null,
  _pendingHandle: null,
  send: [Function],
  _send: [Function],
  disconnect: [Function],
  _disconnect: [Function] }
```

ChildProcess which has disconnected:

```js
ChildProcess {
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: { internalMessage: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _closesNeeded: 2,
  _closesGot: 1,
  connected: false,
  signalCode: null,
  exitCode: 0,
  killed: false,
  spawnfile: '/usr/bin/nodejs',
  _handle: null,
  spawnargs: [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', './dist/child.js' ],
  pid: 25424,
  stdin: null,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null,
  stdio: [ null, null, null, null ],
  channel: null,
  _channel: [Getter/Setter],
  _handleQueue: null,
  _pendingHandle: null,
  send: [Function],
  _send: [Function],
  disconnect: [Function],
  _disconnect: [Function] }
```